# X Axis on graph in Power BI does not display full date range

Tags: powerbi

I am new at Power BI and created a column chart to display events for every month in a 13 month period. The X axis is displaying all the data, but the naming of the months is not correct as it skips every second month. Does anyone know where I can change this as I suspect it might only be a format change.

I have attached a screenshot to show the x axis.

Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ljXr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please go to X-axis in format tab in Visualizations and change type from Continuous to Categorical.
[Type as Categorical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDrBJ.png)

Create a calculated column as follows and sort it using Date field

MonthLabel = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(LEFT([Date].[Month],3)," "),Right([Date],4))

Hope this helps!

Best Regards,

Shani Noorudeen